# Is there ENUM type in Presto?

Tags: enumeration, presto

I was looking at the docs for Presto here https://prestodb.io/docs/0.172/index.html
I can't find the ENUM type, is it not supported? What do we use instead? Arbitrary strings or arbitrary strings? Asking for a friend.

Comment: Don't know PrestoDB, but can't you just use a string with a constraint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presto has no enum-like type. You can think of enum type as "`varchar` with constraints". Since Presto is a query engine, not a database, it does not own storage. For this reason, it is "by design" hard to have a type with additional constraints.

Supported data types are listed in the docs: https://trino.io/docs/current/language/types.html

However, note that starting with [Presto 306](https://trino.io/docs/current/release/release-306.html), Presto e.g. does support PostgreSQL's `enum` type.